# php == vs === operator

Tags: php, comparison, operators, equality

What is the difference between == and === in php. I am unsure when to use both.

*Updated note:* So that it shows up in StackOverflow search, the difference between == and === is the same as the difference between != and !==.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646/how-do-the-equality-double-equals-and-identity-triple-equals-compariso