# What's the difference between !== and != in PHP?

Tags: php, conditional-operator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php == vs === operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589549/php-vs-operator)

What's the difference between !== and != in PHP?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589549/php-vs-operator

Comment: I can guess it's a duplicate ^^

Answer (score 5):

`!==` is strict not equal and which does not do type conversion

`!=` is not equal which does type conversion before checking

Answer (score 4):

`===` AND `!==` checks if the values compared have the same **type** (eg: int, string, etc.) and have the same **values**

While...

`==` AND `!=` only compares the **values**

Answer (score 3):

```
"1" != 1     // False
"1" !== 1    // True
```

It's a type thing.  `!==` takes into account the types of its operands, while `!=` does not (the implicit conversion makes the first conditional false).

Answer (score 3):

`==` is only true if the values are equal.
`===` is only true if the values and types are equal.

Answer (score 1):

the triple equal also make sure the two variable are from the same type

```
1 == `1` // is ok
1 === `1` // is not same.
```

Answer (score 1):

Both are [comparion operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

- **$a !== $b** Return TRUE if $a is not equal to $b, or they are not of the same type.
- **$a != $b** Return TRUE if $a is not equal to $b.