# PHP if this and either that or that, how?

Tags: php, if-statement

I need help figuring out how to make this IF work. It basically checks IF first condition AND either of (second or third condition) are true.

```
IF ( ($a=1) && ($b=2 || $c=3)  ) {
   echo "match found";
};
```

Answer (score 6):

You should have double equal(comparison operator) signs when trying to see IF a,b and c are equal to 1,2 and 3 respectfully.

```
if(($a==1) && ($b==2 || $c==3))
{
    echo "match found";
}
```

Also, in order to use proper syntax it would be better to write the IF in lowercase letters and remove the semicolon at the end of the if statement.

Comment: while the capitalized IF and stray semicolon are both bad style, neither causes an actual functional issue.

Comment: So you're saying it's better not to let the guy know?  Honestly i don't see why this answer deserves two downvotes...

Comment: It's worth mentioning those, but only after explaining the more important functional issue: confusing the assignment and comparison operators.

Comment: i understand semi column i don't like it myself but why not capitalize if it stands out better to me when capital

Comment: @Poemm it's okay to capitalize, it just doesn't follow the common tradition that most people follow.

Comment: I believe only lowercase `if` is valid in most C-like languages.  PHP is the exception, being much looser with case sensitivity than most of its siblings.  That's why many programmers (who often have experience with multiple C-like languages) will favor lowercase keywords like `if`.

Answer (score 3):

```
if ( ($a == 1) && ($b == 2 || $c == 3)  ) {
   echo "match found";
}
```

You were using assignment operators (`=`) rather than comparison operators (`==`).

Here is a link to some PHP documentation about operators: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php

Answer (score 3):

```
if (1 === $a && (2 === $b || 3 === $c)) {
    echo 'Match found';
}
```

**Why have I written it this way around?**

When checking vars against values, putting the value first:

1. Makes it easier to skim-read your code *(arguable)*
2. Triggers an error if you accidentally use `=` instead of `==` or `===`

**Update:** To read about the difference between the `==` and `===` operators, head over to [php == vs === operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/589549/706138)

Comment: +1 for "yoda conditions", but the use of `===` could use some explanation -- if $a $b or $c contain string values, `==` might be more appropriate.

Comment: @Frank Ha, "yoda conditions". Never heard them called that before. *Like it I do*

Comment: If you are truly all about clarity, then why not write it as 

((1 === $a) && ((2 === $b) || (3 === $c))?

It helps when reading code at 3am.

Comment: @gabriel ...because that's kinda overkill. Putting braces around everything doesn't make code clarity any better. Even at 3am.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the proper operator.  Currently you are setting all your variables equal to 1, 2, 3 respectively.  This causes each statement to always evaluate to true.

The correct comparisson operator is `==`

Answer (score 2):

Well the issue i can see is you are assigning variables in your IF statement

```
    IF ( ($a==1) && ($b==2 || $c==3)  ) {
```

Might work better