# What's the difference between == and ===?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php == vs === operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589549/php-vs-operator)
>   [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

In PHP, what is the difference between `==` and `===`? Also, what's the difference between `!=` and `!==`? Appreciate the help!

Comment: Let me guess, you have spent no time googling this?

Comment: As a note, searching for "PHP ===" on this site is not helpful.

Comment: @baudday,  just realized you are the OP.  Yeah, I tried a couple obvious googles myself and didn't see any top results.  Searching on this site for it sucks too.  Seems like something that should be improved.  Searching for "===" on a programming site should be treated pretty well.

Comment: yeah instead I got -5 votes haha. I was just curious cause I'm using `strpos()` to search a string and noticed `!==`. I had been using `!=` so I wanted to know which was correct.

Comment: @baudday google or not, there's still the php.net manual; == and === are, as in any language I think, operators. A search for "Php operators" there would have yielded a better result. A piece of advice: always head for the manual, it's pretty comprehensive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

```
$a == $b    Equal   TRUE if $a is equal to $b after type juggling.
$a === $b   Identical   TRUE if $a is equal to $b, and they are of the same type.
$a != $b    Not equal   TRUE if $a is not equal to $b after type juggling.
$a <> $b    Not equal   TRUE if $a is not equal to $b after type juggling.
$a !== $b   Not identical   TRUE if $a is not equal to $b, or they are not of the same type.
```

Comment: just to add an example: 0 == false, but 0 !== false, the prime example for its use being the strpos function (http://php.net/manual/de/function.strpos.php)

Comment: AWESOME! The whole reason I'm asking this actually has to do with `strpos()`!