# What is the PHP best practice for using functions that return true or false?

Tags: php, function, boolean, typing

After playing with PHP, I discovered that true is returned as 1 and false as null.

```
echo (5 == 5) // displays 1
echo (5 == 4) // displays nothing
```

When writing functions that return true or false, what are the best practices for using them?

For example,

```
function IsValidInput($input) {
  if ($input...) {
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Is this the best way to use the function?

```
if (IsValidInput($input)) {
  ...
}
```

How would you write the opposite function?

```
IsBadInput($input) {
  return ! IsValidInput($input);
}
```

When would you use the `===` operator?

Comment: You asked at least 4 questions.  What is your _real_ question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> After playing with PHP, I discovered that true is returned as 1 and false as null.

That is not true (no pun intended). PHP, like many other languages, has "truthy" and "falsy" values, which can behave like `TRUE` or `FALSE` when compared to other values.

It is so beause PHP uses weak typing (vs. [strong typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_typing)). It automatically converts different types of values when comparing them, so it can eventually compare two values of the same type. When you `echo TRUE;` in PHP, `echo` will always output a string. But you passed it a boolean value, that has to be converted to a string before `echo` can do its job. So `TRUE` is automatically converted to the string `"1"`, while `FALSE` is converted to `""`.

> When would you use the === operator?

This weak, or loose, typing is the reason PHP uses two equality operators, `==` and `===`. You use `===` when you want to make sure both values you are comparing are not just "equal" (or equivalent), but also of the same type. In practice:

```
echo 1 == TRUE; // echoes "1", because the number 1 is a truthy value
echo 1 === TRUE; // echoes "", because 1 and TRUE are not the same type (integer and boolean)
```

> When writing functions that return true or false, what are the best practices for using them?

Be precise when you can, returning the actual boolean `TRUE` or `FALSE`. Typical cases are functions prefixed by `is`, like `isValidInput`. One usually expects such functions to return either `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

On the other hand, it's useful to have your function return a "falsy" or "truthy" values in some cases. Take [`strpos`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php), for example. If it finds the substring in position zero, it returns `0` (int), but if the string is not found, it returns `FALSE` (bool). So:

```
$text = "The book is on the table";
echo (strpos($text, "The") == FALSE) ? "Not found" : "Found"; // echoes "Not found"
echo (strpos($text, "The") === FALSE) ? "Not found" : "Found"; // echoes "Found"
```

Comment: I think this question deserved a better answer, so I completely rewrote mine. Previous version available [here](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9643134/3).

Comment: Additional info: ["official" stackoverflow question/answer on `==` vs. `===`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589549/php-vs-operator)

Answer (score 2):

```
function isValidInput($input){
    return ($input ...);   // if your test returns true/false, just return that result
}
```

Your last example is missing an argument, otherwise fine:

```
function isBadInput($input){
    return !isValidInput($input);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I fixed the typo. Yes, the function was not a good example, but I just wanted to make the example explicit.

Answer (score 1):

1. Sure. Unless you need it in a different sort of structure, e.g. a while loop.
2. You never would. Always invert the normal function directly.
3. When you need to differentiate `false` from `0`, `''`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

> After playing with PHP, I discovered that true is returned as 1 and false as null.

No.. `true` and `false` are returned as boolean `true` and `false`. *When you echo output* it must be cast to a string for display. As [per the manual](http://nz.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting):

> A boolean `TRUE` value is converted to the string `"1"`. Boolean `FALSE` is converted to `""` (the empty string). This allows conversion back and forth between boolean and string value.

As for the rest: that's fine, yes, yes, when you want exact type matches, to avoid type juggling in comparisons, e.g. `"1" == true` is true but `"1" === true` is false.

Answer (score 0):

```
function isValidInput($input) {
  return ($input...);
}

if(isValidInput($input))
  ...

if(!isValidInput($input)) // never rewrite inverse functions
  ...

if(isValidInput($input) === false) {
  // Only run if the function returned a boolean value `false`
  // Does the same thing as above, but with strict typing.
}
```