# Why this function return true?

Tags: php

```
<?php

var_dump(in_array('ddds', array(2,3,0)));
```

Why this function return true? We have a string which could be converted to 1 but why to 0?

Comment: `in_array('ddds', array(2,3,0), TRUE)` returns false, properly, when you enforce strict checks.

Answer (score 4):

[Because 'ddds' is equal to 0 .](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12151997/why-does-1234-1234-test-evaluate-to-true)

Comment: @kingkero: **Equal.**

Comment: var_dump('ddds' == true) and var_dump('ddds' == 0) return true but true == 0 is false? it's strange

Comment: @user2886388: Welcome to PHP.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `ddds == 0` is true ([demo](https://eval.in/73589)), and 0 is an element of your array. Set the `strict` parameter for [`in_array()`](http://php.net/in_array) to ensure the types are also considered.

From the [documentation](http://php.net/in_array):

> If the third parameter strict is set to TRUE then the in_array() function will also check the types of the needle in the haystack.

```
var_dump( in_array('ddds', array(2,3,0), TRUE) );
```

Output:

```
bool(false)
```