# PHP - Why some string function name without underscore e.g strlen?

Tags: php, string, function, str-replace, strlen

I've notice some PHP string function are used with underscore and some are not

Here are examples

```
strlen()
strtolower()
strtoupper()
strpos()
```

etc..

String function with underscore

```
str_replace()
str_word_count()
str_split()
str_repeat()
```

etc..

I expect those function name should be like these

```
str_len()
str_to_lower()
str_to_upper()
str_pos()
```

Comment: I assume it's because PHP is not a strict language and has had many different developers working on it for multiple years, which leads to such inconsistencies.

Comment: Yeah...I don't really see any obvious groups of behaviors which would explain the two naming schemes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20335922/why-is-php-inconsistent etc etc etc etc

Comment: They do have some aliases like `sizeof` and `count` so maybe they will use it for having more unified function name. Or  not.

Comment: does it in the end matter? do you guess what the function manes are? or look them up?

Answer (score 1):

Many of these functions are named after the C functions which they are patterned after. This isn't specific to string functions; a lot of other basic PHP functions are copied from C programming interfaces: `printf()`, `fopen()`, `fnmatch()`…

[`strlen()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strlen) is a perfect example. The C function is functionally identical to the PHP function.

`strpos()` doesn't literally appear in the C standard library, but [`strstr()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strchr) and [`strchr()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strchr) do; the naming pattern is pretty clear. (The distinction between `strstr()` and `strpos()` isn't relevant in C, as returning a pointer to a substring doesn't have any overhead.)

There isn't a `strtoupper()` or `strtolower()` in C either, but there is a family of functions which convert strings to various types of numbers (`strtol()`, `strtof()`, `strtoull()`, etc), which may have inspired these names.

As an aside, the old MySQL extension was similarly a direct replica of the MySQL C API, even down to grody details like the name of [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-real-escape-string.html).