# PHP considers P == 0

Tags: php, types, conditional-statements

This is absolute insanity.  I was testing a post variable today that should always evaluate to a single character.  Example code is...

```
if($_POST['status'] == '' || $_POST['status'] == 0){ die('oh no!'); }
```

If I pass a status of P, it was executing the die statement.  I then created a PHP file with the following code...

```
echo 'P1: '.intval($_POST['status']=='').'<br />';
echo 'P2: '.intval($_POST['status']==0).'<br />';
echo 'P3: '.intval('P'==0).'<br />';
```

Guess what?  P2 & P3 both evaluate to TRUE.  The intval is there just to show 0 instead of nothing on P1.

Is this a known bug of PHP?  Is this just something that is broken on the version I am running?  Frankly, I'm at a complete loss as to why it is doing this.  It evaluates correctly using triple equals, but not on double.  P definitely doesn't equal 0 in my book...

Comment: `P definitely doesn't equal 0 in my book` change the book, for PHP one. It is known feature, not a bug.

Comment: Seriously?  Where is that documented?  Do you have a source link?

Comment: possible duplicate of [php == vs === operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589549/php-vs-operator)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php#types.comparisions-loose

Comment: Thanks for the source.  That makes sooo much more sense.  :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php):

> If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the comparison performed numerically.

Comment: Waiting 8 more minutes and I'll accept it.  Man, that just doesn't seem right, bit it looks like it is.

Comment: @GameCharmer: it's the same in most other languages that are type-permissive. php tries to do its best to interpret what you want, but if you insist on doing "giraffe == plasma tv", then it's just GIGO...

Comment: @GameCharmer It's convenient if you try to compare `3 == '3'` for example, which we do very often in PHP. `'P' == 0` is counter-intuitive but follows that very same logic.

Answer (score 1):

Read the php manual on comparison's. http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

> If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves
>   numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the
>   comparison performed numerically.

If you don't want to have the conversion to happen you need to use triple equals.

`$a === $b`

> TRUE if $a is equal to $b, and they are of the same type

Where `$a == $b`

> TRUE if $a is equal to $b, and they are of the same type.

.

Answer (score 1):

While comparing string and number by using `==`, PHP converts that string to number.

The string `'P'` doesn't have any numeric character in it. Therefore, PHP
evaluates it to number `0`. Finally `0 == 0` happens, which is `true`.

On the other hand, if you use triple equals (`===`), that mentioned conversion
doesn't happen. PHP expects their types to match as well. Because one of them is
string, other is number, it returns `false`.