# MySQL resource, fetch(), and looping

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, resources

i had a headache over the last few days trying to understand this snippet of code. it's about retrieving data from a database table nothing hard (i'm using mysql) . but i'm trying to understand the code. here is the code:

```
<?php
include 'PDOconnect.php';
//Query
$result = $connection->query('SELECT * FROM video_games');
//Fetch
$data = $result->Fetch();

while ($data = $result->Fetch()) {
echo $data['name']."<br />";
}

?>
```

first let me explain, the second line is including the connection code to the database i'm using the PDO way of connecting. the connection is fine . my table is called video_games and it had a column called 'name'. and i'm trying with this code to retrieve all the data from the column 'name'.

1- so what i want to understand is what is the $result variable (line 6) , i've heard it's a Resource. what a resource in mysql means, and what's inside of the variable $result is it the whole table or what exactly ??

2- what the function fetch() does ?? it's confusing .

3- what i know from studying the basic syntax of php is that inside the while condition 
the value must be true in order to execute the code inside.
but here there is ($data = $result->Fetch()) .

4- is the fetch() method automatically incremented ?? i mean why it is working successfully inside the while condition, so it must be incrementing over and over again ??

please help my mind is blowing right now.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php

Answer (score 1):

$result is not a Resource,. it's a `PDOStatement`. see the docs: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php

Once a `PDOStatement` is executed (automaticalyl using -`>query()`) the statement holds the result the database returned.

Everytime you `->fetch()` it returns the current row the Statement is pointing to. After that it points it pointer to the next row (so yes, 'automatically incremented).

Now, your code:

Everything inside `if` and `while` statements is evaluated using loose comparision (==)

`if ( $a )` actually checks or `$a == true`.

`$data = $result->fetch()` simply sets a value to `$data`. Then the while checks or `$data == true`. IF so, it does what it has to do. (see [php == vs === operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589549/php-vs-operator) for more about comparisons in php)

Now, a little remark on your code: the first row is not outputted since you don't do anything with the first fetched result. Simply remove

```
//Fetch
$data = $result->Fetch();
```

So your code would become:

```
<?php
include 'PDOconnect.php';
//Query
$result = $connection->query('SELECT * FROM video_games');

while ($data = $result->Fetch()) {
echo $data['name']."<br />";
}
```

A good tutorial about PDO: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/

Comment: On a note, $connection is a Resource

Comment: it is not actually. a resource with properties? `*wink*`. the rest of the answer is almost perfect though.

Comment: You may wish to actually remove an extra call to fetch for the "proper" version

Comment: @YourCommonSense whoops, looks like I was to fast on that "proper" version. I should indeed be more specific on that 'resource'. PDO is a wrapper around a resource. Programmers be lazy *wink*

Comment: Well, `$result` is indeed a "resource" too, in such terms.

Comment: @YourCommonSense It is, but not the resource mentioned in the question

Comment: `*sigh*`. I am afraid you doin't quite understand what a resource is and how to tell it from object. Ever stumbled upon this page http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php by chance?

Comment: Ah, looks like I had a wrong image of a 'resource'. thx for the link

Answer (score 1):

> 1 what is the $result variable

It is not a [resource](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php). It's actually an **object** of [PDOStatement class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php)

> 2 what the function fetch() does ?? it's confusing.

A manual page is always at your service. Just type `PDO fetch` in the browser's address bar and click the first link opened. It is extremely easy and no less powerful.