# php for true/false parsing of content

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a simple yes/no or true/false boolean type line to parse content depending on the answer.

Like this:

```
<?php
dangerous = "yes";
?>

<?php
dangerous = "no";
?>
```

A block down here similar to `isset`, that will parse if the answer above is `yes`, and to not appear if anything else other than `yes` is written.

```
<?php if dangerous = yes ?>
Dangerous content here.
<?php endif; ?>
```

I'm new to PHP, so I'm not sure what route to go with here.

Comment: I hope that's just pseudo-code, because as is, it's invalid PHP and will never say anything OTHER than `Dangerous content here`, because you're doing assignments everywhere (`=`), not equality tests (`==`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, this line here will **always** evaluate to true, because you are using a single `=` which is an [assignment operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php):

```
if($dangerous = 'yes') // this will always be true
```

You need to use `==` for a comparison operator, or `===` for strict comparison which takes variable types and values into consideration as well. [For more info on the difference between the comparison operators, see here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589549/php-vs-operator)

The way you're doing it currently is pretty widely used, but is not the best practice. Your variable `$dangerous` will be set every time, and you need to check for the **value** of it to determine whether to evaluate your conditions or not:

```
if($dangerous == 'yes') {
    // do dangerous stuff
}
```

Better practice, as you've said, is to use a boolean variable which will evaluate to true or false (above example in this same test will evaluate to true in both cases):

```
$dangerous = true; // or false;

if($dangerous) {
    // do dangerous stuff
}
```

Likewise, if it's not dangerous:

```
if(!$dangerous) {
    // pretty safe, but this will evaluate to true for false, null, zero etc
}
```

In this example, `!$dangerous` will evaluate to true when `$dangerous` is null, zero etc, so if you need a strict comparison for the value of false, you'll need the `===` comparison operator:

```
if($dangerous === false) {
    // false evaluates to true when comparing for a false value
    // false evaluates to false when comparing for a null value
}
```

Better to use a boolean variable over a string representation of a result in most cases. Something to keep in mind though is that if your your boolean variable represents the return of a function call, it might not always be consistent.

Answer (score 1):

```
if($dangerous == "yes"){
    //do something
} else {
    //do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if($yes){
    ?>
        <b>This is my HTML.</b>
    <?php
}else{
    ?>
        <b>This is other HTML.</b>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if ($dangerous === 'yes'): ?>
yes
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ($dangerous == 'no'): ?>
no
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the use of an [assignment operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php) (=) when you should be using a [comparison operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) (== / ===) and comparing variables and value correctly.

For your case

```
<?php 
if($dangerous === "yes"){
  //Dangerous content here.
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use code like this:

```
$dangerous = true; // or false if no

// check result
if ($dangerous) {
    // dangerous!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the conditions for dangerous content and apply php expeptions:

```
 if(dangerous){
 try {
   echo inverso(5) . "\n";
   echo inverso(0) . "\n";
 } catch (Exception $e) {
  echo 'Excepción capturada: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
 }

 }
```