# "array_key_exists()" not working properly

Tags: php, arrays, array-key-exists

### Code

```
$descriptionArr = array( "uk/page"=>"", "uk/page-two"=>"description of page 2");

function getDescription($uri){
    if (array_key_exists($uri, $descriptionArr)) {
      return $descriptionArr[$uri];
    } else {
      return false;
    }
}
```

### Situation

- When i call the function with argument "uk/page-two" it returns the description
- When I call the function with argument "uk/page" it returns false instead of the empty string

### Issue

I would like it to return the empty string and only return false when the argument passed does not exist as key in the array.

Comment: Did you try making the value 'NULL' instead of empty string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
$descriptionArr = array( "uk/page"=>"", "uk/page-two"=>"description of page 2");

function getDescription($uri, $descriptionArr){
    if (false !== array_key_exists($uri, $descriptionArr)) {
      return $descriptionArr[$uri];
    } else {
      return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't, because `$descriptionArr` is not available inside the function.

Comment: It works, I do have the array within the function, so that isn't the issue.

Can someone explain what the `false !== array_key_...` does exactly?

Comment: the `===` (and `!==`) disallow type conversion. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589549/php-vs-operator

Comment: The function already returns a Boolean, so the explicit !== is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your function to the following:

```
function getDescription($uri) {
    if (isset($descriptionArr[$uri])) {
      return $descriptionArr[$uri];
    } else {
      return false;
    }
}
```