# little trouble with OR operator

Tags: php

i got into some trouble by using OR if one condition is true and the other false.
in my constillation right now it is always only the second condition token.

```
if($num_rows === '0' OR $_GET['id'] !== $_SESSION['UserID']) 
{ echo "show me something"; }
else
{ show nothing; }
```

i get only always 'show nothing'.

Comment: Why are you using `===` and `!==` (instead of `==` and `!=`)? Also, `$num_rows` is probably an int so you should just be using `$num_rows == 0`.

Comment: ...plus `$_GET` will always supply a _string_, while userID sounds like it might be an integer value, so `===` will fail.

Comment: When `mysql_num_rows` fails it will return `FALSE`.

Answer (score 2):

Note that `===` is strict comparison. I think the following:

```
$num_rows === '0'
```

should rather be:

```
$num_rows == 0
```

`$num_rows` is presumably an integer and not a string (a piece of text).

Related: [PHP `==` vs `===`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589549/php-vs-operator) on Stack Overflow

Watch out with the second comparison, too:

```
$_GET['id'] !== $_SESSION['UserID']
```

Here, it's probably better to use `!=` in favor of `!==` as well. `$_GET` is generally read as string, so even something like `?id=5` will return as `string "5"` and not as `integer 5`

Here's a quick test to illustrate:

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    echo '<h2>Comparison with == 5</h2>';
    var_dump( ($_GET['id'] == 5) );
    echo '<h2>Comparison with == "5"</h2>';
    var_dump( ($_GET['id'] == "5") );
    echo '<h2>Comparison with === 5</h2>';
    var_dump( ($_GET['id'] === 5) );
    echo '<h2>Comparison with === "5"</h2>';
    var_dump( ($_GET['id'] === "5") );
}
else {
    echo 'Please set an ?id to test';
}
```

This will output (notice the third item is *false*) the following with `?id=5`:

> **Comparison with == 5**
>
> boolean true
>
> **Comparison with == "5"**
>
> boolean true
>
> **Comparison with === 5**
>
> boolean false
>
> **Comparison with === "5"**
>
> boolean true

Answer (score 1):

Probably because you use absolute equality with a string.`Mysli_num_rows` returns an int.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

> Equal and of the same type

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to use === as it is a strict comparison and `$num_rows` is probably an `int` Try this:-

```
if($num_rows == 0 OR $_GET['id'] != $_SESSION['UserID'])
```

`$_GET['id']` will provide you a string. You may chech the **[manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)** for details

Answer (score 0):

To be really correct, need something like this:

```
if ($num_rows === FALSE)  {
    echo 'db resource/link gone';
}
elseif ($num_rows === 0 || intval($_GET['id']) !== intval($_SESSION['UserID'])) {
    echo 'no db result or id mismatch';
}
elseif (intval($num_rows) > 0 && intval($_GET['id']) === intval($_SESSION['UserID'])) {
    echo 'everything good';
}
else {
    echo 'something unhandled went wrong';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all the answers. i got it to work. i change the order and the opreator to what you've suggested.

i made it like this:

```
if($num_rows > 0 OR $_GET['id'] == $_SESSION['UserID']) { echo "show nothing"; }
else { show me some      stuff }
```

so thanks again for all the help. :)